# Double value get rounded while converting to string after entering 14th digit before decimal point

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am using large `double` value as like below code

```
double value = 99999999999999.99;
this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString("N");
```

But the `TextBox` value gets rounded off and I get the below value in `TextBox`

> 100,000,000,000,000.00

Can anyone tell me how can I get the exact value without rounded off?

Comment: Is it floating point question day? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

It's because double precision is 15-16 digits (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) and your number consists of too many digits for it.
I would suggest to use decimal type instead for such numbers like this:

```
decimal value = 99999999999999.99M;
```

M suffix makes the number of type decimal instead of double.

Answer (score 1):

Well you ran out of the precision of a double datatype. Try using decimal instead:

```
decimal value = 99999999999999.99M;
this.textBox1.Text = value.ToString("N");
```

gives

```
99.999.999.999.999,99
```